# Creating a custom structural directive

Tags: angular, directive

I've started learning Angular2 and the newest angular4 a week ago, and now I need to create a custom structural directive that shows what is inside it.

Explanation: I have an element of an array of a pair of string let's call the first element of the n elements of the array title and the second description
this is the result https://ibb.co/i23Dxa

(the array comes from a backend, I'm simulating it through a mock array file)

Now, if I call the structural directive that I need to create, I want that it shows what I'll write under that call

example:

```
<ng-template aulos-configuration-item-toolbar>
    <button (click)="click()">just click</button>
</ng-template>
```

this should only render the button that I wrote in between the tags, for now, I have this:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ 
    selector: "[aulos-configuration-item-toolbar]",

})

export class AulosConfigurationItemToolbar {
    public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {
        this.templateRef = templateRef;
    }
}
```

Could someone explain me better the way to proceed? Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you read <ng-content select="my-directive">?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me explain
Component looks like this...

```
export class GridOptionsComponent { }
@Directive({ selector: 'grid-options' })

@Component({
    selector: 'my-grid',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './grid.component.html'
})
export class GridComponent {
    ....
    ....
}
```

grid.component.html  looks like

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
    <div> some more html elements, components </div>

    <ng-content select="grid-options"></ng-content>
 </div>
```

and usage in another component should be

```
<my-grid>
   <grid-options>
        <button >Add</button>
        <button >View</button>
   </grid-options>
</my-grid>
```

Comment: I've imported into app.module.ts "GridComponent" on NgModule, also i've exported it to make it public to all Component.
Then on the other component, i've imported GridComponent, but my-grid was not found, like if i didnt imported it on app.module, removing it compilation is fine, no errors, but buttons arent shown

(if we could talk through email would be better: fede.benedetti9@gmail.com, it would be faster and i ll update this question with the final answer)

Thanks, btw

Comment: This is the [plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/3y9CJ0pn48fixwgQzhcp/)
it's just to show you my files and let you understand better my problem

Your solution as i read on internet is deprecated, as now <ng-template> is used
Also, i need to pass an item to the ng-template, with let-item
I need to understand better how a directive is built, hope you can help me ^^

Comment: "Your solution as i read on internet is deprecated", provide any reference?

Comment: Ill post what i read in one of the next comments ill do, but for now, i need help doing that thing using ng-template and custom directives
Im sorry if you felt some aggression by my side, wasnt supposed to be like that

Pm me, if you want, we'll talk there ^^

Comment: No, there are few things, you need to look, template is deprecated and should be using ng-template...   However what you really need is ng-content...    if you understand the difference at all..

Comment: any source to look at? Angular documentation about that is very short..